# SQL Array Column; Combine all Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, nltk, cakephp-3.0

In my SQL-database is a column with arrays. Every array consists of many arrays

> ["word",NUMBER]

like the examples $rowOne,$rowTwo,$rowThree. The length and the words of the arrays can be diffrent. I analyzed many texts with NLTK. Now i want to combine all texts of a category in order to get for example the most common words of a category.

> $rowOne = [('love', 14), ('let', 12), ('rain', 12), ('yea', 7), ('oh', 7), ('make', 5), ('happy', 3), ('dream', 3)];
>
> $rowTwo =[('la', 12), ('high', 10), ('fun', 6), ('sun', 6), ('two', 5), ('fly', 5), ('one', 5), ('bridge', 4)];
>
> $rowThree = [('deal', 33), ('ya', 19), ('gotta', 7), ('know', 6), ('another', 5), ('take', 5), ('thrill', 4), ('get', 4)];

The aim is to fetch all $rows the user of my WebApp want, that can often be thousands of rows, and combine all arrays to one $result array ordered by the Number,

My approach now is to build a $combinedArray and so long rows to combine existing the function combineTwoArrays integrate one rowArray into the $combinedArray.
But I'm very unhappy with this solution and the performance, because the array grows and grows...

```
function combineTwoArray ($combinedArray, $arrayToCombine)
{
    $result = $combinedArray;
    foreach ($combinedArray as $element) {
        foreach ($arrayToCombine as $combineElement) {
            if($element[0] == $combineElement[0]{
                $number = $element[1] + $combineElement[1];
                $word = $element[0];

                $array = [$word,$number]

                array_push($result, $array);

            }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**I hope there is a better and faster solution... !! :/**

*Every row has a unique song-ID and one better approach could be to make a new table.*

- i can identify the rows with the id
- but how should i split my array... ?!?! for each array position ('love', 14) a new column or the Numbers also separated?

I tried to build a SQLFiddle, but i think it doesn't work. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e929)

Comment: use merge for that
reference go to http://php.net

Comment: the better solution IMHO should be not to use a columns to store arrays but rather create a dedicate table and a `hasMany` relationship between the twos

Comment: i updated my question and tried to build a SQLFiddle, but i don't know if it works, because i never used it befor... [SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e929)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother merging the array.
It would be faster and easier to acchieve creating a dedicated table with the words and counts, like arilia already mentioned.
So the table would look something like this:

```
song_id    word     word_count
1          hello    20
2          bye      3
```

Then you can use the sql function sum to sum like this:

```
select *, sum(word_count)
from tablename
group by word
```

If you want to furhter filter your results by for example only looking for the number of words in specific songs you can query:

```
select * sum(word_count)
from tablename
where song_id in (<ids of the songs you want to search for>)
group by word
```